# Emacs temp dot hash file don't exist

Tags: grep, find, emacs

I use `find | xargs grep` a lot when working on large source code and when I didn't save a file in Emacs it creates `.#SomeFile` and grep give error that there's not such file (I'm not including because it's localized)

The same when I run:

```
ls -A dir/ | grep '^\.#' | xargs file
```

I've got:

```
.#SomeFile: ERROR: cannot open `.#SomeFile' (No such file or directory)
```

Why is that?

Comment: Could you show us the _actual_ name of the file in question? Also, `emacs` backup files are usually `#foo#`, not `.#foo`.

Comment: @terdon I have both those files when working with `Emacs`, but grep have no problem with `#File#`. I have this problem with any file so it doesn't matter what name it have just pick random one.

Comment: Files with such names (and some others) are temporary files, which stay around just for a short while. Between `find` seeing the file name and calling `grep` on it it might be gone.

Comment: @vonbrand no, they stay until you save a file in Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the problem was, Emacs was creating broken symlinks:

```
$ file .#xxxx 
.#xxxx: broken symbolic link to `kuba@jcubic.1581:1393008109'
```

Comment: Broken symlink wouldn't give _file not found_ error unless you are following symlinks.

Comment: `grep` give me error. `grep: .#xxxx: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu` (sorry: I don't know how to change locale)

Comment: These symlinks are used by Emacs as lock files (in case you try to open the same file in multiple instances of Emacs, it will warn you that your edits would overwrite each other).

Comment: @Gilles yes, I just ask on SO why Emacs create this file, and there was already such question, so it was mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not really have *anything at all* to do with dotfiles.  When you say:

```
ls -A dir/
```

it would display the contents of the directory, e.g. list files like `foo`, `bar`, ...  Now when you attempt to pipe the list to `xargs`, the latter would attempt to find those in the **current directory** and pass/fail depending upon whether those filenames exist in the current directory and `dir` or not.

Create a symlink to the desired file in `dir` in your current directory and you'd notice that your command would start working:

```
ln -s dir/.#Somefile .
```

---

You should be using `find` instead:

```
find dir -maxdepth 1 -name '\.#*' | xargs file
```

and you'd see the *expected* results.

---

You might also want to refer to [Parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: At the begining of the question I said that I've used `find | xargs grep` but grep give me localized error so I didn't include that.